# \restylefloat does not restyle properly threeparttable caption

Tags: tables, floats, captions

The following code does not produce the result I would expect. When the caption position is changed by restyling the caption it is no longer centred; it moves to the left.

Any idea on how to fix the problem (I don't want to move the inside threeparttable caption).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{komaabove}
\restylefloat{table}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcommand{\uhrule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mcc}{o o m}{% 
    \IfNoValueTF{#1} 
    {\multicolumn{1}{c}{#3}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
            {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#3}}
            {\multicolumn{#1}{C{#2}}{#3}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{L{0.15}
            S[table-format=6]
            S[table-format=5]
            S[table-format=2.1, 
              table-space-text-post = {**}]
           }
\toprule
Race
& \mcc[1][0.20]{Population\tnote{b}}
& \mcc[1][0.20]{Homicides}
& \mcc[1][0.10]{Rate\tnote{c}} \\ \uhrule

Black\tnote{d} & 29986   & 12114 & 40.5* \\
White          & 199686  & 12153 &  6.1  \\
Other\tnote{e} & 19038   & 635   &  3.3** \\ \midrule
Total          & 248710  & 24932 & 10.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[a] Data developped from the Statistical Abstract of the United States -- 1993.
\item[b] Population in $1000$s.
\item[c] Rate per $100\,000$ in the population.
\item[d] The rate for \emph{Black} males was 69.2, for \emph{White} males it was 9.0.
\item[e] About one-half of the \emph{Other} category was composed of Asian Americans and Native Americans.
\end{tablenotes}
$*p<.001$, two-tailed test. $**p<0.05$, two-tailed test.
\caption{Homicides by race of the victim in 1993 in the USA.\tnote{a}}
\label{tab5}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your code, the table is still centered, but the caption moves to the left.Do you get a different result?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Yes, the problem is the caption moving to the left. I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `threeparttable` environment uses the caption placement inside it for deciding the typesetting. So, although this might be inconvenient, you need to place `\caption` before the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{komaabove}
\restylefloat{table}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcommand{\uhrule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mcc}{o o m}{% 
    \IfNoValueTF{#1} 
    {\multicolumn{1}{c}{#3}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
            {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#3}}
            {\multicolumn{#1}{C{#2}}{#3}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Homicides by race of the victim in 1993 in the USA.\tnote{a}}
\label{tab5}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.15}
            S[table-format=6]
            S[table-format=5]
            S[table-format=2.1, 
              table-space-text-post = {**}]
           }
\toprule
Race
& \mcc[1][0.20]{Population\tnote{b}}
& \mcc[1][0.20]{Homicides}
& \mcc[1][0.10]{Rate\tnote{c}} \\ \uhrule

Black\tnote{d} & 29986   & 12114 & 40.5* \\
White          & 199686  & 12153 &  6.1  \\
Other\tnote{e} & 19038   & 635   &  3.3** \\ \midrule
Total          & 248710  & 24932 & 10.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[a] Data developped from the Statistical Abstract of the United States -- 1993.
\item[b] Population in $1000$s.
\item[c] Rate per $100\,000$ in the population.
\item[d] The rate for \emph{Black} males was 69.2, for \emph{White} males it was 9.0.
\item[e] About one-half of the \emph{Other} category was composed of Asian Americans and Native Americans.
\end{tablenotes}
$*p<.001$, two-tailed test. $**p<0.05$, two-tailed test.
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had found out that you could do it this way, although the formatting is not quite the same as when placing caption at the bottom of the table; more precisely the caption does not fit the width of the table when at the top. Mind you I am not sure it's a problem!

Comment: I found out that if you remove the lines \floatstyle{komaabove} and \restylefloat{table} then the caption formatting is correct.

Comment: @Pierre Fitting the caption to the size of the table is surely one of the bad things about `threeparttable`.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is indeed problematic with small tables. Table notes would be as well. You can renew \TPTminimum, but then this would not look good with centering. Maybe centering is simply not the right thing to do with tables.